# Декодирование текста в JSON

Tags: python

Кодировал Json Для записи в БД (тип - текст):

```
data_json_for_writeDB = json.dumps(jsonData_user, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Все хорошо записалось. Теперь взял данные из БД  и декодирую:

```
data_decodeJson = json.loads(text_jsonDB)
```

Возвращает с обратным слешем:

```
...,\"FontSize\":0.0,....
```

Конечно можно на [сайте](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) исправить код, но думаю что я что-то не то делаю...

Собственно сам вопрос - можно ли ответ получить без этих обратных слешов?

Дополнение:

1. В принтах норм - все красиво.(Принты сделаны до помещения в словарь)
2. Эти данные, помещаю в словарь, преобразую и отправляю

```
jsonify({"key1": data1,
        "data_format_user": data_decodeJson,
        "key2": data2})
```

3. И cмотрю в постмане что пришло. Там появляются эти слеши только в данных по ключу `data_format_user`

[image: Вид из постман]
[image: Остальные данные без обратного слеша]

4. Для соответствия данных вопроса и скрина заменил ключ`data_decodeJson` на `data_format_user`

Comment: И если напечатать так же со слешами показывает? Вы где эти бэкслэши видите? Может это внутреннее представление просто. Если вся строка в двойных кавычках, то внутренние двойные кавычки будут показываться с бэкслэшами.

Comment: В постмане смотрю. Хм Вывел в принт - там норм...

Comment: Так. В каком месте тут вдруг возникает `Postman`, вы это потом ещё и из веб-сервера куда-то отправляете?

Comment: @CrazyElf, внес дополнения

Comment: Ну а как вы себе представляете процесс превращения в JSON строки с кавычками внутри? Они должны экранироваться, иначе это не будет корректная строка. `JSON` помещает строки в кавычки. `data_decodeJson` будет помещено туда как строка в кавычках. Покажите, что вы видите в `Postman`, и объясните, как там должны выглядеть кавычки, если они находятся внутри строки. На той стороне, где эти данные принимаются, всё должно нормально восприниматься, не должно быть никаких проблем.

Comment: @CrazyElf, добавил скрины

Comment: Ну вот. Как вы себе представляете тоже самое без бэкслешей: `"{"email": ..."` - так? То есть в кавычках будет `"{"`, дальше `email"` без открывающей кавычки и т.д. или как? Просто подумайте - как такой синтаксис можно вообще разобрать и понять? Бэкслэши вам просто показывают, что эти кавычки находятся внутри строки, обозначенной такими же кавычками. Но физически в этой строке (когда это именно строка где-то в переменной) нет никаких бэкслэшей, это просто конвенция такая для отображения кавычек внутри кавычек. И для передачи такой информации через `JSON`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, нет я думал, что он нормально переведет вот так: **{"email": "..."}**

Comment: @АлексейБелкин А, т.е. не строка, чтобы была, а объект... Ну, надо смотреть как `jsonify` вообще работает, может я и не прав.